# How do I expire elements using Javascript / Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I understand how to use Ajax.Updater to make requests and insert the results into a DIV.

What I do not understand is how to expire those elements after some time period.

So in this scenario reports will be received and will be added to the list.  But they should also be expired / removed after a few seconds in the list.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the element is inserted, you can set a timeout (`setTimeout`) to delete the element after some time:

```
new Ajax.Updater('container', {
    onComplete: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // remove the element here
        }, 60*1000); // 60 seconds
    }
});
```